Improving MF accuracy with a split-prism
After using a Canon A1 for a little while, I still struggle to get sharp images when I’m using a wide aperture and close focus. Even with a split-prism viewfinder, it’s difficult to see that I’ve missed focus slightly until I look at the scans.
My right eye is 20/20 but I can’t find a way to get that last adjustment dead-on.
There must be some technique to this or alternative methods? All the photos I see posted online are dead sharp, well the ones from good photographers anyway.

Can you post some samples? It's almost certain that the lenses for your Canon A1 don't perform at their best wide open, and probably the sharp photos you see online were not taken at full aperture either. Not to mention that you may be looking at lower resolution representations online than the resolution at which you're examining your own photos.

My technique when using the split prism manual focusing aid -- see if you can locate a straight-line somewhere in the vista. Reposition the camera so that this line centers the split prism. Now angle the camera by rotating it about 10 or 15 degrees off level. Now manually focus making the view of the straight-line uninterrupted. You will find that focusing with the camera angled helps a lot. Then recompose leveling the camera and take the shot.

Isn't this why in some focusing screens the split-prism is in a diagonal so you are more likely to get an intersection with a line of your subject?

Hi xenoid -- You are correct -- Also the split prism sometimes is useless if the focal length is long or very short. It's super helpful but some situations fail that's why the prism set is surrounded by a super fine ground glass area. This area is actually best when doing critical work.

"Wide aperture and close focus" is a recipe for trouble.  The diameter of blur on objects is focal length divided by aperture number, scaled by their relative distance from the focusing plane.  If the focusing plane is close to the camera (what "camera" means gets hand-wavy when the camera/lens size itself becomes relevant), that relative distance becomes large fast.
For macro photography, you tend to use very narrow apertures far into the range of diffraction (the effect of diffraction is more or less constant on the image and not dependent on the subject) and then use computational means of sharpening (like RL deconvolution) that also work uniformly across the image and reverse the effects of diffraction at the cost of amplifying noise and causing ugly ringing circles around any dust specks in the image not affected by diffraction (like sensor dust).
For macro/closeup, it is often more convenient not to use the camera's focusing but stick with a constant focusing distance and vary the camera position instead, like using a macro sled.  You can then take a focus series and select the best shot or use focus stacking to combine the differing sharp parts of your photographs into a single image.
When indeed using split-image focusing, it tends to help to have good light, correct diopter adjustment (make sure that you see any non-image elements in the viewfinder as sharp as possible) and do "focus hunting" by turning the focus back and forth and trying to settle in a central position of what was off to one or the other direction.
And of course if you can, avoid wide open aperture for anything but focusing: that's why even SLRs from the 60s do framing and focusing wide open and close down only for the shot itself.  It will usually be easier to get good focus at F2 with a lens that has a maximum aperture of F1.4 than one that has a maximum aperture of F1.8 because then you focus at a wider aperture.
When a macro lens provides you with an aperture of F2.8, that doesn't mean that this kind of aperture is a good choice for photographs, but it does help with framing and focusing.

In my experience with split prism close focus is no different in principle. There is no secret for close ups specifically. Split prism only works well when you have a sharp enough contrast transition perpendicular to the line of split.
If you don't have such detail then you must find two opposite focusing distances when object is clearly just barely out of focus and estimate instinctively where the middle is between those.
If you ask me I like microprisms much more, they can produce jitter in the OOF image and be reliable with much smoother objects.

F/8 and be there
Many of your lenses on an A-1 are going to be primes, with very wide maximum apertures relative to (cheaper) zooms that are more common these days.  If you're used to shooting wide open maybe stop down a little to f/5.6 give-or-take.  A wider depth-of-field will cover a lot of human imprecision.  Even if you won't get that nice razor-thin separation of subject from background.

"f/8 and be there" for close focus? In the context of close focus, I feel like you're missing the point of OP's question.

@scottbb I missed the close-focus part.  More depth of field probably still helps right?

Depends on what the OP is going for. Some close-focus shots intentionally use shallow DoF. Hopefully OP will add some examples...
